# Making an ESP32 based flight controller

Tags: remote-control, esp32, drone, quad-copter

I'm trying to make a flight controller for brushless quadcopters with ESP32 using external sensors like MPU6050(Gyro & accel), BMP180(Baro), HMC5883L(Compass). I've seen lots of people make this kind of flight controllers running the MultiWii firmware and use Arduino Mega, Nano, Minis etc.

But, how do I use the MultiWii firmware for the ESP32? The pin layout is different and I have no idea if just changing the I2C pins on the code would work or not. Writing the entire flight control software from scratch is also probably not an option. I'm not really software savvy and mostly a hardware guy. Is there any existing MultiWii firmware for ESP32? Or any other alternatives? Any resources would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept STM32, you should definitely look at [Betaflight](https://betaflight.com/), it's a full opensource firmware stack for a quadcopter.

It has a whole bunch of [libs for the different sensors](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Supported-Sensors).

It is considered as the reference for quadcopters.

Note that many many manufacturers make boards for this purpose at a fairly low cost, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.